# Java: How to use Scanner class to read text file in resources folder

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File source;
        Scanner input;
        String name;
        String id;
        Pokemon x;
        ArrayList<Pokemon> pokelist = null;

        try {
            source = new File("/resources/gen1pokemon.txt");
            input = new Scanner(source);
            input.useDelimiter(",");
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                id = input.next();
                name = input.next();
                x = new Pokemon(id,name);
                pokelist.add(x);

                input.nextLine();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println(pokelist.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

I have a text file in my resources folder and I am trying to read that using the Scanner class, however I get an error.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \resources\gen1pokemon.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)Exception in thread "main"

Any ideas what could be causing this? I looked around and tried putting "class.getResource("file name")" reference, but I got an error doing that too when declaring file.

Answer (score 3):

Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

To use the URL in a scanner, [get an input stream from it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--), then use [`new Scanner(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.InputStream-).

Comment: input = new Scanner(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/gen1pokemon.txt"));

Doing that fixed it, thanks, but now I'm getting a null pointer exception, by looking at the code could you figure out what could be causing that?

Comment: Update the **question** to show the current code, and note when doing so: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `/src/resources/gen1Pokemon.txt`?

Paths can be a bit tricky, try about with different versions depending on the project's structure.